# How to reload login page after successfully logout in Nest API iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am working a iOS application using Nest Apis, I am able to `login` and `logout` to my nest account by presenting the `NestWebview`.

But the problem comes when i `logout` and try to `login` ones again,`NestWebview`directly showing `Accept page` not `login page`. So My requirement is when user logout successfully, It should show `login page` instead of Accept Page.

For logout I am using below line of code as suggested by Nest Documentation.
 https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/deauthorization-overview/  :

```
curl -v -X DELETE 
"https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_tokens/<access_token>"
```

**How its working login first time.**

`Click on Nest login` -> `Open login page` -> `After successfully,Accept login page` -> `Click on Accept button` -> `Get device list`

**How its working after Logout.**

`Click on Nest login` -> `Accept login page` -> `Click on Accept button` -> `Get device list`

So After logout successfully,

> Login page is missing.

Is their any way i can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar problem few month back.I Query them and after few days later i got response from the Nest.

"*I believe you are wondering why you get the permission page with the 
"Accept" button instead of a login page after revoking a token. The reason 
is because you still have a valid web session and thus single sign-on is
 attempting to authorize using an existing session. If you scroll to the bottom of the permissions page, you will find a link "Sign in to a different account >" This link clears the existing session and forces the user to login screen.*"

Hope it help you understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response@Vivek . I will look into it and let you know if it work for me..

Answer (score 1):

clearing cookies will help you to bring Login page back, do this when loggingOut.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```